# Including custom header files (ANSI C)

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, ansi-c

I have made some header files and placed them in the same folder as the main program, but the compilation command `gcc -ansi -Wall *.c` cannot find those files. Do I have to include the full directory path of the header files or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Te C tag implies standard C. ANSI C (aka C89) is not standard anymore since ~17 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to include the header files into the relevant C-files if you haven't already done so as such:

```
#include "path/to/file.h"
```

You also have to tell the compiler to compile the .h-files so if your .h-files are in the same foder as you .c-files and you want to include all the present .h-files your compiler command would look like this:

```
gcc -ansi -Wall *.h *.c
```

Comment: Is there any way I can avoid placing the entire directory path?

Comment: Using the full path is probably the easiest way. Otherwise you could maybe place the headers in one of these locations: /usr/local/include
     libdir/gcc/target/version/include
     /usr/target/include
     /usr/include [more on includes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)